# Running API Calls in Parallel , Still running in sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm calling an API to analyze some files and return data. I have to use this on a couple of hundred files, so I figured I can make the calls run in parallel, since the analysis of the file and the result ( to be written to its own file ) have no relation to each other.

My pseudocode was along the lines of - get list of files from folder, for every file kick off a request, wait for response and write respective file. I wrote the following code but it still seems to run in sequence rather all in once. What am I doing wrong ?

```
import os
import asyncio
import json
import time

path = "/home/repo/"
result_path = "/home/repo/Results/"


async def to_json(obj, file_name):
    with open(result_path + file_name + ".json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as wr:
        await json.dump(
            obj, wr, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__
        )


class AnalyzeFile(object):
    async def start_analyze_file(self, file_name):

        endpoint = "https://api.com/"
        key = "key"

        print("Creating a recognizer client")
        async with FileClient(endpoint=endpoint, key=key) as client:
            with open(path + file_name, "rb") as f:
                file = await client.analyze_file(model_id=model_id, stream=f.read())
        file_result = await file.result()
        print("Results are back for %s" % file_name)
        print("Analyze ended at %s" % time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())))
        print("Writing to file")
        await to_json(forms, file_name)
        print("Done writing to file")


async def main():
    af = AnalyzeFile()
    for file_name in os.listdir(path):
        await sample.start_analyze_file(file_name)
    print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: For one, you're not reading the file using async code, so that's going to block.

Comment: dont you need some sort of sleep or yeild in these things to actually have them run "in parallel" ?

Comment: Secondly, now that I look at that, you're awaiting within the `for file_name` loop, so it's serializing things too.

Comment: And, all in all, if all of your components aren't `asyncio` aware, just use `multiprocessing` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords `async` & `awake` might not work in the sense you used them. You need to add `@background` signature to the function you need to execute. So that it may run in parallel. And to just that one function. In your case `start_analyze_file()`. As follows:

```
def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

def to_json(obj, file_name):
    with open(result_path + file_name + ".json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as wr:
        await json.dump(
            obj, wr, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__
        )


class AnalyzeFile(object):
    @background    
    def start_analyze_file(self, file_name):

        endpoint = "https://api.com/"
        key = "key"

        print("Creating a recognizer client")
        with FileClient(endpoint=endpoint, key=key) as client:
            with open(path + file_name, "rb") as f:
                file = await client.analyze_file(model_id=model_id, stream=f.read())
        file_result = await file.result()
        print("Results are back for %s" % file_name)
        print("Analyze ended at %s" % time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())))
        print("Writing to file")
        await to_json(forms, file_name)
        print("Done writing to file")


def main():
    af = AnalyzeFile()
    for file_name in os.listdir(path):
        af.start_analyze_file(file_name)
    print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```